# FormKit vue 3, textarea input, doesnt reflect rows prop

Tags: vuejs3, formkit

Im using Formkit, and i want to determine how big is the textarea throw the rows prop, but for some reason is not working:
``

```
<FormKit
type="textarea"
name="notes"
:rows="2"
:value="datigenerali?.notes"
label="Data Giornale"
:classes="formKitClasses" />
```

https://formkit.link/0765f45004e1e2951fc7c7011a6c30f1
i tried to do to they playground and the result is still the same, the prop rows, is not reflected, it gets passed to the component, but it doesnt reflect the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formkit is applying `h-24` to the `textarea` preventing it from taking the `rows` height,

as a workaround, you can overwrite the height using inline style

```
  <FormKit
    type="textarea"
    rows="10"
    //Setting height to auto
    style="height: auto;"  
    label="FormKit Input"
    help="edit me to get started"
  />
```